# Three js textureloader display CORS error to load data from S3 Bucket, in iframe from Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, amazon-s3, iframe, three.js, cors

This is my THREE JS Code:

```
var aws_image_path = "path-to-aws-s3-bucket-image"
myTextureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
myMap = myTextureLoader.load(aws_image_path)
// Further I used myMap for SpriteMaterial.
```

This code is working properly in web browser using https://my_url/

I add this URL at iframe in angular app.

My Ionic code is:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <iframe class="iframe" [src]="https://my_url/" allow="camera;microphone"></iframe>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

In App S3 image is not loading. It displays a CORS error.

Error:

```
Access to image at 'path-to-aws-s3-bucket-image' from origin 'https://my_url/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

AWS CORS Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I used DomSanitizer in IFRAME but show the same error.

Comment: Is the parent document also on the same `https://my_url/` domain as the iFrame document?

Comment: This seems specifically related to CORS configuration, and not to any of the libraries tagged (`icon-framework`, `three.js`), though I would leave `amazon-s3` in place because a solution could be made specific to that service.